# Dynamically assign names to arrays

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to create dynamic array and its name should be dynamic also. We can create dynamic array using `new` operator. But I need to give its name dynamically. I don't have any idea about this. So how can we do this?

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<T>>`

Comment: can you please explain how this can be done?